# I wonder how to locate specific points in outputs in mathematica

Tags: mathematica-frontend

The following is my code.

```
as = Flatten[Import["e:\\matlab\\piturn\\Nor_bms\\as.mat"]];
da = AccountingForm[
Flatten[Import["e:\\matlab\\piturn\\Nor_bms\\da.mat"]]];
For[i = 1, i < 2304, i++, ghdparam = Table[0, {i, 1, 909}, {j, 1, 5}];
For[j = 1, j < 910, j++, 
path = "e:\\mathematica\\abs_5s\\" <> 
StringTake[ToString[AccountingForm[da[[1, j]]]], 8] <> "\\" <> 
as[[i]] <> ".mat";
If[FileExistsQ[path], abs = Flatten[Import[path], 1], Continue[]];
abms = abs[[All, 1]] - abs[[All, 2]];
Print["i=", i];
ghdparam[[j]] = 
FindDistributionParameters[abms, 
HyperbolicDistribution[\[Lambda], \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Delta], \
\[Mu]], ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]；Print["j="];
 Print[j];
 Export["e:\\mathematica\\continuous\\" <> as[[i]] <> ".mat", 
 ghdparam];
 Clear[path, abs, abms]]]
```

[image]
This image is part of outputs of my code in mathematica. "i=1" means the first loop in out loop and "j=2" means the second loop in inner loop. And now I want to locate the point with error information. For example, in this picture, only when i=1 and j=5, there is no error information. And then i want to get list of j points with error, just like {1,2,3,4}. for the program will be looped many many times, i want to do this by code. May someone help me! thank you!

Comment: `Do[Check[1/i, Sow[i]], {i, 2, -2, -1}] // Reap // Rest`

Comment: Thank you very much! I get your point. It's awesome!